# Override New page Cancel button not working

Tags: visualforce

I have the following page to override the new page:

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Time_Sheet__c" 
    action="{!URLFOR($Action.Time_Sheet__c.New, null, 
        ['Name'='New'], true)}">

    </apex:page>
```

It pre-popoluates the name field as I want, but cancel just cycles back to this page.  How do you get cancel to exit the page?

Thanks.

Comment: normally this is handled by the value of retURL parm in the URLFOR

Comment: I have tried: {<apex:page standardcontroller="Time_Sheet__c" 
    action="{!URLFOR($Action.Time_Sheet__c.New, null, 
        ['Name'='New', 'returl'='a0I/o'], true)}">

</apex:page>}

Comment: Is the returl supposed to be in quotes 'returl', or returl, no quotes?  Anyway, I still just go back this page after cancel.

Comment: Does someone have a working URLFor for overriding NEW for Opportunity or Account so I can see an example of working syntax.  The examples on the internet have the problem I am seeing with cancel not working.

Comment: Here is the syntax that finally worked for me:

Comment: <apex:page standardcontroller="Time_Sheet__c" 
    action="{!URLFOR($Action.Time_Sheet__c.New, null, 
        [Name='New', retURL='/a0I/o'], true)}">

</apex:page>